# I'm getting an error when trying to install ROS

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I get the same error every time I follow the steps to install Ros. Even though I tried different codes and gpt's solutions, none of them worked. I even deleted Ubuntu and reinstalled it. I would be happy if you help.
`~$ sudo apt update`

```
Same: 
1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Download: 
2 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB] Same: 
3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease 
Download: 
4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB] 
Ignore:
5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Download: 
6 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [560 kB] 
Error: 
7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release    404 Not Found [IP:] 
Download: 
8 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1.326 kB] Reading packing lists... Done 
E: There is no Release file in the repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release'. 
N: Updates cannot be made securely from such a repository, so the repository has been disabled. 
N: Detailed information on repository creation and user configuration can be found in the apt-secure(8) man page.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to install ros-noetic (ROS 1) to Ubuntu-22 (jammy) Which is not supported. Try installing ros-humble (ROS 2) instead.
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html

Comment: have you tried removing ROS 1 related ppa from source list and before installing ROS 2? 
You can chek using following command `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ | grep ros-`. If you get any output, it means there are still some ros-related ppa present that is not supported in ubuntu-22. You can remove those using the following command `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-*`

Comment: İt worked! My problem is solved. Thank you very much.